# How to use this CSS on Chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I tried to create simple date icon using CSS. Below is the code, which is working fine on Mozilla Firefox, but not working on Chrome.

[Code link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-calendar-icon)

How can I fix this so it works on all browsers?

HTML code:

```
 <div class="holder">
    <div class="month red">
        <p>October</p>
    </div>
    <div class="day">
        <p>22</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
holder {
    width: 72px;
    height: 84px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
}
.month {
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
.month p {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.40);
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    margin: 5px 8px 0px 8px;
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
}
.day {
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    background: white;
    
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(247, 247, 247, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,rgba(247, 247, 247, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f7f7f7',GradientType=0 );
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff, 0px 2px 0px 0px #ccc,0px 3px 0px 0px #fff, 0px 4px 0px 0px #ccc;
}
.day p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px white;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.red{
    background: rgb(169,3,41);
    
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(109,0,25,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Comment: It looks fine on Chrome and Opera (latest versions) for me.

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome - http://i.stack.imgur.com/KXgLK.png

Comment: hi all please give me new version link

Comment: [How to update Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?hl=en).

Comment: Click `Hamburger Icon` on top right of chrome > `About Google chrome`. Then your chrome will check for new version and get updated automatically